# List of coordinates filtering

Tags: python, loops, lambda, list-comprehension, list-manipulation

In python I have a list of contours (each holding x, y, w, and h integers), I need to somehow iterate over the list and check, if the current x + w is greater than the last x + w by less than 3 (which mean by 1 or 2) remove the current one, otherwise keep going.

I have this for now:

```py
contours_v2 = [[551, 0, 2, 1], [491, 0, 1, 1], [484, 0, 6, 1], [482, 0, 1, 1], [480, 0, 1, 1], [400, 0, 6, 1], [321, 0, 6, 1], [319, 0, 1, 1], [238, 0, 1, 1], [234, 0, 3, 1], [229, 0, 4, 1], [227, 0, 1, 1], [225, 0, 1, 1], [223, 0, 1, 1], [142, 0, 1, 1], [132, 0, 6, 1], [130, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 7, 1]]
last_x_w = contours_v2[0][0] + contours_v2[0][2] # Initialize with the first contour's x + w value
i = 1 # Start with the second contour
while i < len(contours_v2):
    current_x_w = contours_v2[i][0] + contours_v2[i][2]
    if abs(last_x_w - current_x_w) < 4:
        contours_v2.pop(i)
    else:
        last_x_w = current_x_w
        i += 1
```

I Need a few things:

1. It's not working on all of the cases, sometimes I still have ones that should have been poped.
2. I was wondering if there is a way to do it with lambda or list comprehension

### Updates:

If I  move the `i += 1` into the `else` statement, the resulting list will be (input list was the example I provided):

```py
# As you can see, the item didn't pop and should have popped is
# the one with x = 229, its next one is x = 227
# contours_v2
[[551, 0, 2, 1], [491, 0, 1, 1], [482, 0, 1, 1], [400, 0, 6, 1], [321, 0, 6, 1], [319, 0, 1, 1], [238, 0, 1, 1], [229, 0, 4, 1], [227, 0, 1, 1], [223, 0, 1, 1], [142, 0, 1, 1], [132, 0, 6, 1], [130, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 7, 1]]
```

Comment: You could fix the problem by adding `continue` in the if-clause after `contours_v2.pop(i)`.

Comment: I tried to put the `i +=  1` in the `else` only, but then it popped too many of the items

Comment: Then something of the requirements isn't clear to me. Should `last_x_w` also be set to the removed items? Did you maybe mean `if abs(current_x_w - last_x_w) < 3:`?

Comment: I can add the `abs` function to make it both ways, but for example, if I'm now `1` and the next one is `3` so delete `3` but then the next one is `4` so it won't be deleted and `4` will be compared with the next one (I hope this is clearer), plus I want to find a somewhat efficient solution using lambda or list comprehension

Comment: If you move `i += 1` into the `else` part, can you show an example where items were wrongly deleted? It is better to have a simple working solution first before optimizing it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I added the result in "Update 1"

Comment: This makes sense because `current_x_w` is always smaller than `last_x_w`, therefore `current_x_w - last_x_w` is negative.

Comment: You are right, I updated my code and now it's much better, but still, a little problem, which I know is against what I said because x=29+4 will be greater.
But the most important now for me is to try and make it with lambada or list comprehension  like I wanted. @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to write shorter (but not necessarily faster) code is

```
from functools import reduce

contours_v2 = [[551, 0, 2, 1], [491, 0, 1, 1], [484, 0, 6, 1], [482, 0, 1, 1], [480, 0, 1, 1], [400, 0, 6, 1], [321, 0, 6, 1], [319, 0, 1, 1], [238, 0, 1, 1], [234, 0, 3, 1], [229, 0, 4, 1], [227, 0, 1, 1], [225, 0, 1, 1], [223, 0, 1, 1], [142, 0, 1, 1], [132, 0, 6, 1], [130, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 7, 1]]

def x_w(c):
    return c[0] + c[2]

r = reduce(lambda x, y: x if abs(x_w(x[-1]) - x_w(y)) < 4 else x + [y],
        contours_v2[1:], [contours_v2[0]])

print(r)
```

The initializer of `reduce` is a list with the first item of `contours_v2`, then for each item of the rest its distance to the last item of the list is checked and by the if-expression either the unmodified list is returned by the lambda or a new list with the new item appended is returned.

The code does some things which may be slower than a conventional loop because it may have to repeatedly calculate `c[0] + c[2]` for the same `c` and it uses something equivalent to `x = x + [y]` which is slower than `x.append(y)`.

Comment: What do you mean by no faster? and can you explain what you did, please?

Comment: @DolevMiz I added some explanations.

Comment: I saw, thank you and about the function `x_w` that you use inside the lambda?

Comment: @DolevMiz It isn't really necessary but I thought it makes the code slightly more readable than to pack the whole calculation into the `abs(...)`.